# Use MongoDB with Django but also use relational database

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm working on a Django application that needs to interact with a mongoDB instance ( preferably through django's ORM) The meat of the application still uses a relational database - but I just need to interact with mongo for a single specific model.

Which mongo driver/subdriver for python will suite my needs best ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use django-nonrel which is a fork of Django and will let you use the same ORM.

If you dont want a forked Django you could use MongoEngine which has a similar syntax otherwise just raw pymongo.

Comment: Can django-nonrel work back and forth between using mongo directed ORM and SQL ORMs ?

Comment: Yes, django-nonrel updates the django orm to cope with nosql as well.  MongoEngine is a separate ORM so either or will allow you to use both.